# Complicated substring and string concatenation

Tags: java, string, algorithm, substring, concatenation

```
String target = "When user fills in #this# in form #that#"
// I have my function in removing all content in between paired "##"
String processedTarget = "When user fills in ## in form ##"
// processedTarget is generated using the function from target

String input = "When user fills in #test#"
// Same function is used in here to process input
String processedInput = "When user fills in ##"
//processedInput is generated using the same way
```

In a simple way(by using only Java built-in methods), how do I generate `" in form #that#"`?
The aim is to compare the user input with the target, regardless of the content between `"##"` of input, but the what's left from target between `"##"` should be rendered.

If the target start with the input (regardless of the content in PAIRED `##`) complete the sentence by returning the rest of the sentence (using a variable named `output` or similar).
If the target does not start with the input(ignore mismatch of the content in PAIRED `##`), return null (`output` should be null).

In the example, input matches target.

Comment: Could you provide an example input with the corresponding expected output?

Comment: @Manu `" in form #that#"`. I have written down after the code block.

Comment: Can you explain why `" in form #that#"` is expected result? Can you walk us through your code and requirements because for now it is kind of unclear.

Comment: @Pshemo Since I really does not care about the content in paired "#" and "#", I remove all content between them. But I need to complete the sentence with what's originally in target (including the content in paired "#" and "#"), that is why `" in form #that#"` instead of `" in form ##"` is the right output.

Comment: If you really want to generate `" in form of #that#"`, then it's a simple search for first occasion of "#this#" in your string `target` and then returning the substring starting from that position, basically an one-liner. I don't really know what you aim for, I don't think it's possible to come up with a good answer when the question is so poorly written.

Comment: @Vlasec I have rephrased the problem. Input is subject to change. Output depends on the input. If input does not match (I have defined "match" in my way above) the target, output is null.

Comment: I am still rather unsure what do you mean by "starts with". This looks a lot like a regexp thing. Anyway, does the content between `##` have spaces in it, or is it a single word? If it's a single word, then I think there can be something called "the rest of". Otherwise, `#that#` can eat the rest and nothing remains.

Comment: @Vlasec The content between `##` can contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a regex like:

```
String regex = "When user fills in #[^#]*# in form #[^#]*#(.*)"
```

And then use it as a `Pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

And there is a matcher that can be used to retrieve results, e.g.:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("When user fills in #null# in form of #void#, he sucks");
```

Then you can use `matcher.matches()` and `matcher.group(1)` to obtain the result, which should be:

```
", he sucks"
```

I am not sure if it's exactly what you wanted, as I don't really know your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transform your userinput to a regex:

```
String target = "foo #word# bar #word# bar #word# foo #word#";
String input = "bar #first# bar #another#";

String regex = input.replaceAll("#[^#]*#", "#[^#]*#");
String output = target.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

`output` becomes `foo #word#  foo #word#`, which is what you want, if I understood your question correctly :)

Comment: If the input does not start with exact(except for content in `##`) `"foo #word# bar #word#"` there should be no output.

Comment: Thanks I am able to write my own. In fact I am doing it. I was just curious if there is a built in function(s) to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`String.replaceFirst(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to remove `processedInput` from `processedTarget`.

To have the second `##` group in the output, you'll have to change your function.

```
String processedInput = "When user fills in ##";
String processedTarget = "When user fills in ## in form #that#"; // Keep the second
String output = processedTarget.replaceFirst(processedInput, "");
```

Comment: `" in form #that#"` is the desired output. So I believe it involves all four strings given.

Comment: Please don't change the String `processedTarget`. It is generated using my own method removing all contents in paired `"##"`. See my latest comment for the problem.

Comment: @JiajuShen The code you provided does not know about what was inside the second `##` group. Therefore, the only way to have it in the output would be to change the method that removes it.

Comment: But the user input can contain arbitrary content including any number of paired `"##"`, I suspect changing the method removing content in paired `"##"` does not help.

Comment: @JiajuShen You'll have to cut what you don't want in the output only. You can ask a new question if you don't know how.